# Cordova Error Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,

Tags: android, cordova

When I write this command in cmd cordova build android, this error happens:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 Where:

```
Script 'H:\prjPath\prjName\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cord
```

ova.gradle' line: 64
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

```
>
No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 1
9.1.0 or higher.
```

Try:

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
```

Option to get more log output.

```
BUILD FAILED
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""H:\prjPath\prjName\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "H:\prjPath\prjName\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pan
droid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

What should I do?!! And this is my SDK manager[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: have you set android_home system environment variable and added android SDK folder to path system variable

Comment: @Gandhi I set ANDROID_HOME, but what do you mean about "added android SDK folder to path system variable " ?

Comment: you gotta add the path of android SDK installation folder to the system variable called 'path'

Comment: @Gandhi ok.I get it. I did this but this error happend again!

Comment: Buy all means this should get fixed if you have latest build tools installed which you already have as per your screenshot. It should be the path problem for sure. Check these  links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304599/error-in-building-android-app-using-apache-cordova http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the